# How to join/merge .wmv files?

Tags: quicktime, macos, video

I have ten .wmv video files that I want to join them as one big file.

Some tutorials indicate this can be done using QuickTime. However, it doesn't work for .wmv files.

Is there a way to join these files on a Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will first want to use HandBreak (free) to convert your .wmv files to .mp4, which can then use according to your tutorial.

Comment: HandBreak is great!